# Need some advice in selection of GAM model - choosing family, etc

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, ecology

I am not a statistician (clearly) and am trying to wrangle environmental data. My data looks like (note data is on time scale - 1 = Day 1, 650 = Day 30:

[image]

[image]

I am developing a GAM model which predicts the effect of environmental variables and anthropogenic variables (i.e. vessel noise) on call rate of an animal. Call rate is transformed to a density metric where calls are divided by detection range so result in small numbers between 1e-3 to e1e-6. Currently I'm using the following model (phase is a factor which captures the behavior of high amount of calling in first 9 days and then lower). I am seeing high amounts of heteroskendacity.

```
fish_vsl_gam <- gam(data = fish_vsl, dens_adj ~  vsl_viz + chorus + fish + s(air_press, k = 5) + s(wind_spd, k = 5)  + s(hour, k = 24) + s(turb, k=5) + s(wave_height, k=5) + s(rms_dif_noise, k = 30) + s(phase, bs = "re"),  family = quasipoisson, method = 'REML')
```

Looking for advice on family choice, method, etc. Anything I should investigate would be helpful. It is possible that variables have different impact depending on phase.